# Code in procedural macro is not added to stream

Tags: rust, rust-macros

I was trying a simple procedural macro following the example from the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/procedural-macros.html), more specifically:

```rust
#[proc_macro_attribute]
pub fn show_streams(attr: TokenStream, item: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    println!("attr: \"{}\"", attr.to_string());
    println!("item: \"{}\"", item.to_string());
    item
}
```

It shows how this macro prepends the function with the two prints.
However, I've tried to reproduce an even simpler case, with my macro being:

```rust
#[proc_macro_attribute]
pub fn test_macro(_: TokenStream, item: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    println!("Macro start");
    item
}
```

I then run my main function of the crate:

```rust
use test_macro::test_macro;

#[test_macro]
fn main() {
    println!("yup");
}
```

And no prints appear.
I thought maybe the `main` method can't have macros attached, so I tested on another function and it didn't work either.
I'm pretty confused, what am I missing?

Comment: It seems to me this happens because I'm actually not modifying the `stream`, however in that case I believe the documentation is either wrong or outdated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing to stdout in a procedural macro will do so at compile time, like the docs accurately state:

> This following example shows the stringified TokenStreams that the attribute macros see. The output will show in the output of the compiler.

As you noticed, you need to return a `TokenStream` with the desired output of your macro. To do this you would typically use the [`syn`](https://github.com/dtolnay/syn) and [`quote`](https://github.com/dtolnay/quote) libraries, which allow you to parse and transform input and create new `TokenStream`s easily with the `quote` macro.

`syn` in particular has a few examples, for an attribute macro take a look at [`trace-var`](https://github.com/dtolnay/syn/tree/master/examples/trace-var).

Comment: Aaah.. I missed that sentence, makes a lot more sense